# How do I create a random link out of specified group of links using within an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do: I want the image on the page to click through to a random link of a pre-determined set of links I have. I figured out how to do the random links using a button but after changing the button to the image, the image no longer clicks through to my links. Instead, it stays on the same page and the url slightly changes at the end.

What do I need to change in my coding to have the image work the same way as the button did (click to one of the random links I set up)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomlinks() {
    var myrandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 2)
    var links = new Array()
    links[0] = "file://localhost/Users/drobert4/Desktop/Simple%20Site/Runaways.html"
    links[1] = "file://localhost/Users/drobert4/Desktop/Simple%20Site/Saga.html"
    links[2] = "file://localhost/Users/drobert4/Desktop/Simple%20Site/MsMarvel.html"

    window.location = links[myrandom]
}
</script>

<form>
    <input type="image" value="random link!" src="openlongbox.png" onClick="randomlinks()" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using input type `image` which acts like submit button. In this case when you click it browser sends GET request submitting the form.

> Instead, it stays on the same page and the url slightly changes at the end.

Since form method is GET by default, it appends query string parameters of the form elements values. Since you don't have any you get just `?` part.

Use something like this:

```
<form>
    <img src="openlongbox.png" onclick="randomlinks()">
</form>
```

However, from your code it seems that you don't really need a form. Just use a button by its own. You can even use

```
<input type="image" value="random link!" src="openlongbox.png" onClick="randomlinks()">
```

but without form tag, in this case there will be nothing to submit and it will work.

Comment: not to mention the form is not being used to submit anything

Answer (score 0):

Just use this, `return false;` in onclick, it will work as expected

```
    <input type="image" value="random link!" 
src="openlongbox.png" onClick="randomlinks(); return false;" >
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the formtags and you will be good to go.